# Supabase Edge Functions errors out with "Unexpected end of JSON input"

Tags: supabase

I'm invoking supabase edge function from React front end.

```
await supabase.functions.invoke('order', 
     { body: { order_id: order_id }, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
)
```

In supabase edge function,

```
Deno.serve(async (req: Request) => {
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
      return new Response('ok', { headers: { ...corsHeaders }, status: 200 })
    } 
    const { order_id } = await req.json();
....
```

Getting error at req.json : Unexpected end of JSON input

Followed the instructions in https://supabase.com/docs/guides/functions. Also tried by adding JSON.stringify to body while invoking the function but all were futile.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. Earlier versions of edge functions required headers but not any more. So merely removing headers worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a GET call into function (hello world example) and the call should be POST.